# textarea is endless , no limit

Tags: javascript

i really search on the internet, but i didnt reach anything.

i have a textarea with javascript.In this textarea, there is no limit, no scrollbar appears.

**You can see the normal view**
[image]

**However when i add too much text, textarea is going under.**
[image]

why dont scrollbar reveal ? 
[You can reach js file from here](http://s2.dosya.tc/server7/cYH5Jh/nicEdit.rar.html)

Comment: Please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), not a file everyone has to download.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KKXM9/1/ you can reach from here

Comment: The jsFiddle shows... Nothing. We need some HTML code too. Try to recreate your scenario in your jsfiddle, otherwise it has no relevance to your question :/.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess it's because you have

```
  overflow: auto;
```

or something like that in you CSS.
You should style it so that it has

```
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
```

and you should be set.

Comment: overflow-x is hidden as default and all overflows are hidden.There is no overflow: auto;

Comment: try adding this to your stylesheet: `textarea {overflow: scroll !important; overflow-x: hidden !important;}`